# Ajax in jQuery not sending the correct Key-Value to PHP formular

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, key-value

Given this two pieces of code:

Javascript:

```
/*  Stores the received song. */
var receivedSong;

/*  Class: goearSong            *
 *  Description: Stores a song  */
function goearSong(link, artist, title) {
    this.link = link;
    this.artist = artist;
    this.title = title;
}

function getGoearLink(code) {
    var key = 'id';
    var value = code;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'goearScript.php',
        data: {key : code},
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Success!");
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("Error..." + response);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert("Failure..." + response);
        }
    });

}

getGoearLink("06b3682");
```

PHP:

```
<?php
function path($id){
  $ip = substr($id, 0, 1);
  $load = 'http://www.goear.com/tracker758.php?f='.$id.'';
  $load = file_get_contents($load);
  $temp = explode("=", $load);
  $num = 3;
  $path = $temp[$num];
  $path = str_replace("\"", "",$path );
  $path = str_replace(" bild", "",$path );
  return($path);
}
function name($id){
  $ip = substr($id, 0, 1);
  $load = 'http://www.goear.com/tracker758.php?f='.$id.'';
  $load = file_get_contents($load);
  $temp = explode("=", $load);
  $num = 5;
  $name = $temp[$num]." - ".$temp[$num+1];
  $name = str_replace("\" title", "",$name );
  $name = str_replace("\" />", "",$name );
  $name = str_replace("\"", "",$name );
  $name = str_replace("</songs>", "",$name );
  $name = str_replace("/>", "",$name );
  return($name);
}

$_id = $_GET['id'];
$_ip = substr($_id, 0, 1);
if($_id){
  $load = 'http://www.goear.com/tracker758.php?f='.$_id.'';
        $xml = @simplexml_load_file($load);
        if ($xml) {
            $path = $xml->song['path'];
            $artist = $xml->song['artist'];
            $title = $xml->song['title'];
            $name = $artist.' - '.$title.'';
            }
        else{
          $path = path($_id);
          $name = name($_id);
        }
}
echo 'new goearSong("'.$path.'", "'.$artist.'", "'.$title.'");';
?>
```

I cannot understand why I am not able to get the correct output when given a correct 'code' value. The function always exits as an error...

The PHP code is correct as it has been tested in my local server with the following string:

```
/localhost/goearScript.php?id=06b3682
```

Can anyone shed some light on this issue? It's driving me mad!

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

It seems that the PHP file was not under the root directory but under **/php/** one. So the problem is solved by changing this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'goearScript.php',
```

To this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'php/goearScript.php',
```

And also changing the line mentioned by the chosen answer. Thanks everybody!

Comment: And what error does it exit with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `$_GET['id']` in your `PHP` file and you are passing `key` as `GET` parameter, you need to pass `id` and also add `dataType: 'text',`

Replace this `data: {key: code},` with this `data: {id: code},` and try

Updated `function getGoearLink` is as below:

```
function getGoearLink(code) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'goearScript.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {'id': code},
        success: function(response) {
            alert("Success!\n" + response);
        },
        error: function(response) {
            alert("Error..." + response);
        },
        failure: function(response) {
            alert("Failure..." + response);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: I have just did that and I am afraid it is not working... Now it looks like **data: {id: code}** but I still get the error output. :S

Comment: It's working for me, which version of `jQuery` you are using?

Comment: You are completely right! It was a dumb mistake I made. Thanks!

Comment: Add `dataType: 'text',` in `ajax` parameters, answer updated, replace `getGoearLink` with above